# The listener for function 'functionName' was unable to start. <--- Forbidden

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to implement azure durable functions in C#
I have few activity triggers there myActitivityTrigger1,myActitivityTrigger2

Its all working fine locally (From Visual Studio). But when I deployed it into azure, it starts saying

> The listener for function 'myActitivityTrigger1' was unable to start. <--- Forbidden

```
[FunctionName("dqService")]
public static async Task<string> InvokeObjectMetadata([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    //log.LogInformation($"ObjectMetadata fired");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Dq Service Fired");
    return $"Hello {name}!";
}
```

What could be the reason this is firing in azure only

Comment: I am sure durable functions need some context, so it would either need it as a parameter or method needs to be instance methane and not static.

Comment: But it functions locally without any trouble

Comment: Validate if the `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection is correctly provided for Azure storage account.

Comment: Yes it is.. Also some other functions using the same storage connection string which works fine

Comment: I've had similar problems when the ```.config``` or ```.json``` weren't copied to the input directory.

Comment: @IvanGechev But locally its working perfect. When deployed into azure this message is showing in live metrics

Comment: @SandeepThomas I can only suggest you check if everything is okay in your ```appsettings.json``` file and if your functionName is properly set - ```"functions": [ "yourFunctionName" ]```

Answer (score 0):

***We have also tried to recreate the issue from our end but its working fine withput giving us any error***.

*Workaround that we follow;*

- *Created Durable function using `.net` and tested locally with the added connection string of our storage account in `localsettings.json` ( in VS CODE) and it returns as expected*.

[image]

- And then deploy the function to our function app and make sure that we have the correct connection string as on `localsettings.json` file because its not being deploy . Then call the function with providing correct uri with function name .

  `https://orc************.azurewebsites.net/api/DurableFunctionsOrchestrationCSharp1_HttpStart`

***OUTPUT DETAILS:-***
[image]

[image]
[image]

*For more information please refer this* [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling?tabs=csharp).